# 'Error: empty email address' doing postbuild in AppCenter

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

I'm struggling with a test project in MS App Center.

I'm trying to make app center run a Xamarin UITest after a commit.

I have added a appcenter-post-build script and after fideling with the paths I'm now getting this error:

```
appcenter test run uitest --app $TEAM_APP --devices $DEVICE_SET --app-path $APPCENTER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/PipelineTest.iOS.ipa --test-series $TEST_SERIES --locale "en_US" --build-dir $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/$UITEST_PATH/bin/Debug --async --token $API_KEY --uitest-tools-dir $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/appPipelineTest1/PipelineTest/PipelineTest.UITests/UITestPackage_*/tools
Preparing tests... done.
Validating arguments... done.
Creating new test run... failed.
Error: empty email address
```

I can't seem to find any information about which email is missing?
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried changing the App token to a User token and it worked.
I'm not sure why.
According to the documentation the App token should work just fine.

> User API tokens have the same rights that you do as a user of App
> Center. User API tokens work across all organizations and apps that
> you're associated with.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/api-docs/

Answer (score 3):

I asked Microsoft team directly because I had the same problem and the answer is:

"For test you need to use the user level token only, app level token was not supported.

Our test team was already working on this but currently there is no ETA on it."